# Assigning the Tag Property of a Control in WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

If I have 7 checkBoxes, one for each day of the week, Can I assing in XAML the Tag property to each one of the the System.DayOfWeek enumeration value?

```
<StackPanel >
   <StackPanel.Resources>
      <system:DayOfWeek x:Key="Monday" >Monday</system:DayOfWeek>
   </StackPanel.Resources>
   <CheckBox Name="chkMo" Tag="{StaticResource Monday}">Mo</CheckBox>
     ...
</StackPanel>
```

Is there a way to assign directly the enum value to the tag without using resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, try the following:

```
 <CheckBox Name="chkMo" Tag="{x:Static system:DayOfWeek.Monday}">Mo</CheckBox>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `x:Static` is not available in Silverlight >= 4. This is a strictly WPF solution (currently).